# Vaishnava Prayogas and agamas

Tags: vaishnavism, tantra, abhichara, prayoga

Does anyone know about vaishnava abhichara prayogas?. There's so little info about them.

Answer (score 1):

The Narada purana lists Various Abhichara prayogas such as Stambhana, Vasikarana and so on many of which are Performed through mantras of Vaishnavite deities.

I am Quoting specifically just the relevant excerpts From [here](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12945/page/n49/mode/2up?view=theater)

> The N.P. (Narada Purana) records the following types of Tantric Sat
> Karmas -
>
> 1. Paustika (bringing pease or prosperity or propitiatory)
> 2. Vasya (Helpful in controlling others)
> 3. Stambhana (Paralysing the other party)
> 4. Vidvesa (creating animosity)
> 5. Ucchatana (expulsion, exirpation)
> 6. Marana (Annihilation, Killing)
>
> **Vasya or Vasikarana** - If Laksmana mantra is chanted one hundred
> thousand times followed by homa of ten thousand lotuses, it enables a
> man to marry a girl of his liking (N.P. 1.73.166-67). If one thousand
> kumuda(night blossoming lotuses) are offered as homa while muttering
> visnu mantra, all kings come under ones control(70.200).While chanting
> Narasimha, the sacrificer can control the whole world.
>
> **Stambhana (Magical power of stupefying and paralysing)**- If while
> muttering the Narasimha mantra, flowers of Madhuka tree and pieces of
> Dhatri are offered, one attains the power of stupefying others(NP
> I.71.84)
>
> **Ucchatana (Extirpation)** - In order to extirpate terrible goblins and
> spirits causing epilepsy,one should mutter Jvala-malini mantra one
> hundred thousand times and worship Nrhari (Nrsimha) with the
> performance of homa with cow's Ghee (NP I.71.100-106)....If the diety is lord Krsna,
> the mantra describing Hari attacking the hostile forces with fiery
> arrows is to be chanted one thousand times every day for the period of
> a week. When total seven thousand chantings is completed, the enemy is
> extirpated in a week (NP. 80.274-276)

Many Vaishnava Agamas also similarly list such abhichara prayogas, The Gautamiya tantra lists Stambhana, Maarana, Vasikarana and ucchatana prayogas with the mantras of Krishna.

**[Gautamiya tantra 28.54-57](https://archive.org/details/gautamiya-mahatantram-sage-gautamasrinivasa-sharma/page/n215/mode/2up?view=theater)**

[image]

[Gautamiya tantra Chapter 27](https://archive.org/details/gautamiya-mahatantram-sage-gautamasrinivasa-sharma/page/n201/mode/2up?view=theater)

[image]

Comment: thank you soooo sooo much

Comment: do you also happen to now what prayogas are used against dhumavati or bagala prayogas specifically in tantric vaishnavism?

Comment: Not sure about that one

Comment: thanks!! Do you happen to other texts agamas or samhitas with similar vaishnava prayogas?